# How to pass images from raspberry pi to jetson tk1

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi

Right now I have a raspberry pi that gets images from a pi camera, however the image processing will be done on my jetson tk1 board. Once processed the jetson will give useful information back to the pi where it will decide what to do.

So the current work flow is

rasp pi gets image -> jetson tk1 processes image -> meaningful result (a string containing where on the image objects were detected) to the rasp pi

Right now I'm quite confused on how to go about getting the images to the jetson. I've never encountered a problem like this before...

Comment: Presumably the two machines are connected somehow? That seems like the most important aspect of the situation, yet you've excluded it completely...

Comment: Right now we use a router for the connection, but I'm open to other suggestions that will be faster.

Comment: I take it that means an Ethernet/WiFi router - in which case the problem is really just "how do I transfer data between two computers over a network". Pretty much every language offers a sockets API, and often various higher-level abstractions on top, for that.

Comment: I'm using ROS operating system, but I'm a little worried about installing it on my jetson. I'm using C++, but I will look into this some more.

Comment: @Zypps987 do you mind sharing your code how did you take pictures from the cameras? or give me some idea? your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @sariii if you're still interested in the code feel free to pm me and i will share the github link